# Twig - access to user object id

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I have problem with display id for user object in Twig (Symfony 3). For example I can dump User object:

```
{% for user in usersObject %}
    {{ dump(user) }}
{% endfor %}
```

and I get result:

```
User {#236 ▼
  -id: 1
  #email: "admin@admin.pl"
  -username: "admin"
  -password: "$2y$13$TW.gB06kBOBtc04Fti176OQBzNRh79G9tDIqNEf098/ADHsQkbM4W"
  -permissions: "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"
  -isActive: true
  -createDate: DateTime {#232 ▶}
  -lastLogin: DateTime {#233 ▶}
  -userCookie: ""
}
```

I can display all elements for this object:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.permissions }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.password }}</td>
</tr>
```

But I can't display ID:

```
<tr>
    <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
</tr>
```

When I tray to use code above I get error message:

```
Method "id" for object "...\....\...\...\....html.twig" does not exist in @.../admin/form/usersList.html.twig at line 15
```

Comment: What happens if you try to add getter method for attribute id:   `public function getId() { return $this->id; }` in `User` entity ?

Comment: Your answer solve my problem - now everything works OK. 

Can you explain why? I think that everything is send in my user object (I saw my data from dump!) and I can get everything from user.XXX instead of entity.

Comment: You didnt post the entity, but i suspect, that you didnt have getter and the attribute was set as private (or protected), so twig couldn't get to it. It's always best if you have getter functions for all classes and relevant attributes... Probably twig uses different mechanism to display dumps, but i would have to study twig source codes for that .. ;)

Comment: It's true that this attribute was display like protected... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in comments above, adding public getter function `getId` to entity `User` helped:

```
public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}
```